# Which is more efficient between __autoload() or include/require?

Tags: php, autoload, micro-optimization

Which has faster execution time: `__autoload` or `include` inside nested if statements?
Which is less error prone between the two?

Comment: do a benchmark or use `spl_autoload_register`. In any case, it's a pointless µ-optimization and the anwer will be of little practical value.

Comment: I don't understand your downvote...

Comment: @mo I didnt dv but the dv is justified because the question isnt useful nor does it show any research effort. µ-opts are largely uninteresting outside an application context and OP can benchmark him/herself if he's interested in that. Besides, the answers to all these type of questions are usually "dont bother, use an opcode cache. write readable code".

Comment: @Gordon this question makes sense. For example in Zend Framework, many classes have explicit require_once in order to improve the performances and avoid using the autoloader.

Comment: @matthieu and the [ZF Performance Guide tells you to strip them](http://zendframework.com/manual/en/performance.classloading.html#performance.classloading.striprequires.sed) in order to maximize autoloader performance and benefit from lazy loading. Apart from that, it's a different question because there is no classes with `__autoload` in ZF.

Comment: @Gordon: you are absolutely right, I was just trying to edit my comment. I also updated my answer. Anyway it still means that there are different performances for autoloading or require.

Comment: @Matthieu well sure, but does it matter? We are probably talking about a difference of 0.0000n seconds. Without the context of an application the numbers are completely meaningless beyond stating x is faster than y - which is uninteresting in isolation. It should not lead to any design decisions.

Comment: I think in a large website, 0.0000n second counts. "Intelectuals solve problems, genius' prevent them".

Answer (score 3):

[`spl_autoload_register`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) (instead of `__autoload`) should be the more robust option: it allows you to write code much more flexible than what is possible with `include` statements, and you can keep everything centralized.

Regarding performance, IMHO it's not meaningful to discuss it unless you have measured that a significant percentage of your page load times are spent on loading includes. Even if this is true, you should use a PHP opcode cache to speed your application up instead of trying to extract marginal benefits from switching between `include` and autoloading.

Comment: @Downvoter: Please help me improve this question by leaving a comment.

Comment: you're questionning what OP wants to do, and you don't know what are his needs. That is a valid question, look at: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/performance.classloading.html (and sorry about the delay for the comment)

Comment: @Matthieu: I am not questioning what they want to do, although I would do so without hesitation if I thought it was a bad idea (if we did not do this, then we would have to close any question where the OP makes even one wrong assumption). The link you provide is not related to this specific question as far as I can tell. And finally, don't you think that my answering the question suggests that I also find it to be valid?

Comment: Well he's asking about performances, your answer suggest spl_autoload_register for "practical reasons" (at least not for performances). And you are saying that it's "meaningful to discuss it unless...". This part should be (IMO) a comment asking "did you measure a significant percentage of your page load times...?" (or something like that, but in a comment). Because maybe he did, maybe he knows what he's doing.

Comment: To summarize: I think you are right questionning his intentions, but that should be in a comment, because else you are giving an answer based on asumptions (that could be right or wrong)

Comment: @Matthieu: It is obvious that they did not measure anything. Anyhow, it looks like we 'll have to agree to disagree.

Comment: Indeed. Though if anyone who did measure the right things, and finds this question, he will not have his answer :(

Answer (score 2):

Just use include/require and get readable, maintainable and standard code. This is much more important than the 0.001 second you *might* save.

By the way, are you really sure you need extreme performance of your PHP scripts? Is the including really the bottleneck?

Comment: you are not providing an answer to the question but questionning what he wants to do. This should be in a comment IMO.

Comment: I am thinking beyond the question and imagining I'm in the position of the asker. I am providing an answer in regards of what he should use.

Comment: "he *should*". How can you tell it won't have a effect (even small) on his performances?

Comment: Because I can't imagine a scenario where it would. It seems very much more likely that he is optimizing in the wrong way/place.

Comment: Well I can, and folks at ZF do too: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/performance.classloading.html. They may not be talking about `__autoload` precisely, but they are still comparing autoloading vs require.

Comment: I'm quoting the site you linked: `While this may seem a micro-optimization`. So they suspect it's micro-optimization but they didn't profile the differences (at least they didn't post it)?

Comment: The part you are quoting is not the right paragraph. Read "How can I eliminate unnecessary require_once statements?"

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/performance.classloading.html

**`require_once` is actually an expensive operation** (checking if the file has already be loaded). **Autoloading will improve your performances**.

As Jon suggested, you might want to try `spl_autoload_register` rather than `__autoload` (see his answer).

However, be aware that this is a small optimization, I'm just providing your question an answer.

Edit: at first, I wrote the opposite of what I suggest now, so I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you're using `include`/`require` or `__autoload`/`spl_autoload` most time will be (in most cases anyway) spent on loading, parsing and compiling the included source code. Execution of those few lines of autolaoder function(s) will hardly matter in comparison.